# AutoCompleteTextView return model after selecting the result

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I am using a `autocompleteTextview` when searching a major and school. In my autocomplete `textbox` it returns an actual strings of searchable queries like

```
major = Computer Science 
schools = Harvard University
```

But after clicking the selected item it returns the model like

**this is my filter code in my school adapter**

```
 @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null){
                List<MTSSchool> filterValue = new ArrayList<MTSSchool>();

                for(int x = 0; x < _filtteredSchoolList.size(); x++){
                    if(_filtteredSchoolList.get(x).getSchool_name().contains(constraint)){
                        MTSSchool university = new MTSSchool(_filtteredSchoolList.get(x).getSchool_name(),_filtteredSchoolList.get(x).getSchoolId());
                        filterValue.add(university);
                    }
                }

                filterResults.values = filterValue;
                filterResults.count = filterValue.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if(results != null && results.count > 0){
                _filtteredSchoolList = (List<MTSSchool>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return filter;
}

  protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if(results != null && results.count > 0){
                _filtteredSchoolList = (List<MTSSchool>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
```

[image]

after selecting the choices in autocomplete this was the output

I noticed to my 3 autocompleteTextview it does not reset the search results but it makes limited on the other autocomplete  any suggeston on this guys?

Answer (score 1):

For the `MTSSchool` class implement a `toString()` method which returns the school's name

Comment: public String toString(){
        return school_name;
    } this is what I added Ill test it

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: i just post the logcat through online whihc is could not be able to seen the problem

Comment: it works now but am having a hard time to reuse my adapter to another autocompleteTextview it does not show any suggestions based on what I search and only be used on one autcompleteTextView   https://shrib.com/ITH4ra8qnSGyvIU   i paste my code i updated the earlier issue